# Why do the foci of an ellipse need to be on the same axis?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

My understanding of a definition of an ellipse is that it is the set of all points such that the sum of the Euclidean distance from the point to two foci $f_1$ and $f_2$ is equal. Or, $\{x \in \mathbb{R^2} \vert d(x,f_1) +d(x,f_2)=a\}$, for some constant $a.$

I keep seeing textbooks then say that the two foci have to be on the same (major) axis, but I don't see why this is the case. Why couldn't we have two foci on completely different axises with this definition?

For instance, look at [this graph I made](https://ibb.co/zPLg2y2). Is this an ellipse, and if not then what is it?

Comment: Not following. There is always a line connecting the two foci.  To be sure, the major axis need not be parallel to the $x$ or $y$ coordinate axes if that is what you are asking.  Note:  your link is broken.

Comment: @lulu Oh yeah, good point thanks. I kept seeing people put it on the x-axis I guess but they're just doing that for simplicity.

Comment: Yes, that's just a matter of convenience.

Comment: A very pleasing ellipse is that with equation $x^2-xy+y^2=1$. You see that it contains all four unit points on the $x$ and $y$ axis, as well as $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$. The axis of the ellipse is…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general equation of an ellipse (centered on the origin) with principal axes of length $a$ and $b$ rotated by angle $\theta$ is:

$$\frac{(x \cos \theta + y \sin \theta)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(x \sin \theta - y \cos \theta)^2}{b^2} = 1$$

If you want to displace the center, replace $x$ and $y$ by $(x - x_0)$ and $(y - y_0)$, respectively.

Note here:  "axes" refers to the *axes of the ellipse*---*NOT* (necessarily) the $x$ and $y$ axes of a coordinate system.  In fact, the two foci (which can be anywhere) *define* the major axis of the ellipse, so of *course* the foci *must* be on the same axis!

Comment: Centered at the origin, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Another general equation is
$$
Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0\,,
$$
in which the graph is an ellipse if $B^2-4AC<0$ and if the graph has at least two points (could be empty or a singleton, as you see in the cases $x^2+y^2+F=0$ when $F$ is positive or zero, respectively.